# finding operator norm $T_N$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

How do find the operator norm of , $T_N\colon c_0\to \Bbb R$ given by

$T_N(y):=\sum_{j=1}^Nx_jy_j$ ,when $N$ is a integer .

TIA

Answer (score 1):

If $x=0$, $T_N=0$. So assume $x\neq 0$.

It is easily seen, by triangular inequality, that
$$
|T_N(y)|\leq \sum_{j=1}^N|x_j||y_j|\leq \|y\|_\infty \sum_{j=1}^N|x_j|=\|x\|_1\|y\|_\infty.
$$
Hence $\|T_N\|\leq \|x \|_1$.

Now consider the sequence $y$ such that $y_n=0$ whenever $x_n=0$ and also for $n>N$. And for the other values of $n$, take 
$$
y_n=\frac{x_n}{|x_n|}.
$$
That's the sign function of $x$. What is $\|y\|_\infty$? What is $T_N(y)$? Conclude that the above inequality is an equality:
$$
\|T_N\|=\|x\|_1.
$$

Comment: :Thanks for your answer. I don't understand how with the triangle inequality you show that  $\|T_N\|\leq \|x \|_1$.

Comment: @Ralph This is simply by definition of the operator norm of $T_N : \ell^\infty \to \mathbb{R}$, for this demonstrates that for any $y \in \ell^\infty$, $\|T_N(y)\|_{\mathbb{R}} := |T_N(y)| \leq \|x\|_1 \|y\|_\infty$.

Comment: @Ralph As Branimir Cacic says, this is by definition. $\|T_N\|$ is the sup of all $|T_N(y)|$ over all $\|y\|_\infty\leq 1$. And for these $y$, we have just shown that $|T_N(y)|\leq \|x\|_1$. Hence the sup is $\leq \|x\|_1$. ie $\|T_N\|\leq \|x\|_1$.